# Tapestry @CommitAfter on method outside page

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

I am trying to perform database transactions outside of the page in a dedicated DAO class.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536659/hibernate-is-ignoring-my-persist-calls) answer helped a little bit, however after following instruction on the [official website](http://tapestry.apache.org/hibernate-user-guide.html) the transactions are still not being committed. I am not getting any errors - I can see the insert queries are being run, but no entries appear in database.

Do the DAO classes and interfaces have to be in specific packages for the `@Match()` to find them? That's the only thing that can be causing the problem that I came up with...

Here is all (I hope) relevant code:

AppModule

```
public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(MemberDAOInterface.class, MemberDAO.class);
}

@Match("*DAO*")
public static void adviseTransactions(HibernateTransactionAdvisor advisor,
        MethodAdviceReceiver receiver) {
    advisor.addTransactionCommitAdvice(receiver);
}
```

MemberDAOInterface

```
public interface MemberDAOInterface {
    @CommitAfter
    public void addMember(MemberEntity memberEntity);

    @CommitAfter
    public void updateMember(MemberEntity memberEntity);

    @CommitAfter
    public void deleteMember(MemberEntity memberEntity);
}
```

MemberDAO

```
public class MemberDAO implements MemberDAOInterface {
    @Inject
    private Session session;

    public void addMember(MemberEntity memberEntity) {
        this.session.persist(memberEntity);
    }

    public void updateMember(MemberEntity memberEntity) {
        this.session.update(memberEntity);
    }

    public void deleteMember(MemberEntity memberEntity) {
        this.session.delete(memberEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious - I would first try putting some logging / breakpoints around the HibernateTransactionAdvisor to see if it's getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwering to this question of yours:

> Do the DAO classes and interfaces have to be in specific packages for the @Match() to find them?

I 've found in the question you mentioned this:

> The @CommitAfter annotation only works in page/component classes by default. To get the same behaviour in service objects, you need that extra piece of code.

So **yes**, your DAO must be tapestry services. You need to put them no the services package.

hope that helps.

Comment: sorry, my bad... it's obvious you 've got your dao's as services as you show you 're binding them. discard my answer please.